# How to update a slider's value with StateProvider?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Trying to set the value of a slider with a Riverpod StateProvider.

The value changes in OnChanged but the slider's value doesn't change. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
final valueProvider = StateProvider<double>(
  (ref) => 0.0,
);

class DynamicCircle extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const DynamicCircle({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    double slider = 0.0;

    final value = ref.watch(valueProvider.notifier);
    return Column(
      children: [
        Slider(
            value: value.state,
            max: 2.0,
            min: 0.0,
            onChanged: (value) {
              print(value);
              ref.read(valueProvider.notifier).state = value;
            }),
        Text(value.state.toString())
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to rebuild your ui and reflect the changes, you have to use 'ref.watch(valueProvider.state).state;'

try this out.

```html
final valueProvider = StateProvider<double>(
  (ref) => 0.0,
);

class DynamicCircle extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const DynamicCircle({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    double slider = 0.0;

    final value = ref.watch(valueProvider.state).state;
    return Column(
      children: [
        Slider(
            value: value.state,
            max: 2.0,
            min: 0.0,
            onChanged: (value) {
              print(value);
              ref.read(valueProvider.notifier).state = value;
            }),
        Text(value.toString())
      ],
    );
  }
}
```